# String Replace in C++

Tags: c++, macos, string

I've spent the last hour and a half trying to figure out how to run a simple search and replace on a `string` object in C++.

I have three string objects.

```
string original, search_val, replace_val;
```

I want to run a search command on `original` for the `search_val` and replace all occurrences with `replace_val`.

**NB:** Answers in pure C++ only. The environment is XCode on the Mac OSX Leopard.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A loop should work with find and replace

```
void searchAndReplace(std::string& value, std::string const& search,std::string const& replace)
{
    std::string::size_type  next;

    for(next = value.find(search);        // Try and find the first match
        next != std::string::npos;        // next is npos if nothing was found
        next = value.find(search,next)    // search for the next match starting after
                                          // the last match that was found.
       )
    {
        // Inside the loop. So we found a match.
        value.replace(next,search.length(),replace);   // Do the replacement.
        next += replace.length();                      // Move to just after the replace
                                                       // This is the point were we start
                                                       // the next search from. 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a small nit to pick, but your function name has a typo ("Repalce") which seems a little out of place in your, very elegant and well formatted, code.

Comment: @Levy: One can only strive for perfection but attaining it is the domain of deities (thus if my only mistake is spelling I am happy).

Comment: I agree this is an elegent piece of code. My only recommendation is to not use verbs for your parameters/variables because they look like function name (replace even is a function name). So your replace() call could read something like target.replace(next,search_string.length(),replacement)

Answer (score 4):

```
size_t start = 0;
while(1) {
  size_t where = original.find(search_val, start);
  if(where==npos) {
    break;
  }
  original.replace(where, search_val.size(), replace_val);
  start = where + replace_val.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For comparison here is the function in pure C:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/libs/string_replace.c

Comment: what does the phrase "string interpolation" mean? I found it in the header of the link you provided.

Comment: If you look up "interpolate" you should get a description. for example shell variable interpolation is the process of replacing $name with "value".

Answer (score 1):

A little bit more elegant:

```
void searchAndReplace(std::string& value, std::string const& search,std::string const& replace) {
    for(std::string::size_type idx = value.find(search);match
        idx != std::string::npos;        
        next = value.find(search, idx + replace.size())   
    )
        value.replace(next, search.size(), replace);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

string newstring = boost::replace_all_copy(original, search_val, replace_val);
```

or, if you want in-place replacement

```
boost::replace_all(original, search_val, replace_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simple...

**But limited to replaceing single char only!!**

```
#include <algorithm>
string foo = "abc.e";
std::replace(foo.begin(), foo.end(),'.','d');

result --> foo = "abcde";
```

Answer (score 0):

This might result in a faster execution and preserves the original if wanted.

```
static std::string strreplace( const std::string &original, const std::string &pattern, const std::string &newtext ) {
std::stringstream ss;           
std::string::size_type last = 0;
std::string::size_type it = original.find( pattern, last );
while( it != original.npos ) {
    if( it-last > 0 ) {
        ss << original.substr( last, it - last );
        ss << newtext;
    }
    last = it + pattern.size( );                
    it = original.find( pattern, last );
}
return ss.str( );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your most concentrated version of string replace:

```
for ( string::size_type index = 0 ;
                       (index = value.find(from, index)) != string::npos ;
                       index += to.size() )
    value.replace(index, from.size(), to);
```

Answer (score 0):

A tested code with examples.

If you want the string returned use this:

```
std::string ReplaceString(std::string subject, const std::string& search,
                          const std::string& replace) {
    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = subject.find(search, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
         subject.replace(pos, search.length(), replace);
         pos += replace.length();
    }
    return subject;
}
```

If you need performance, here is an optimized function that modifies the input string, it does not create a copy of the string:

```
void ReplaceStringInPlace(std::string& subject, const std::string& search,
                          const std::string& replace) {
    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = subject.find(search, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
         subject.replace(pos, search.length(), replace);
         pos += replace.length();
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
std::string input = "abc abc def";
std::cout << "Input string: " << input << std::endl;

std::cout << "ReplaceString() return value: " 
          << ReplaceString(input, "bc", "!!") << std::endl;
std::cout << "ReplaceString() input string not changed: " 
          << input << std::endl;

ReplaceStringInPlace(input, "bc", "??");
std::cout << "ReplaceStringInPlace() input string modified: " 
          << input << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
Input string: abc abc def
ReplaceString() return value: a!! a!! def
ReplaceString() input string not modified: abc abc def
ReplaceStringInPlace() input string modified: a?? a?? def
```