# Get the \n when using istream_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I would like to use an `istream_iterator(std::cin)`

It gives me each word however I am looking for a way to define the `\n` has a word.
My idea was that I should use an iterator on `getline()` and `if iterator == end` I return `\n` and take the other line.

Is this a good idea or is there already a built-in iterator to accomplish this.

EDIT: (sorry for not being understood)

My iterator is created like this:

```
_file = ifsteam("path/to/file");
_tokens = TokenIterator(_file); // TokenIterator is an istream_iterator<string>
```

I am using a getToken()

```
TokenIterator it = myClass.getToken();
TokenIterator end = myClass.getEnd();

while (it != end)
{
  std::cout << *it << endl;
  it = myClass.getToken();
}
```

and getToken looks like this

```
const TokenIterator & getToken()
{
  return *tokens++;
}
```

If my file has

1 2 3\n4

My getToken returns:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

But I want it to return :

- 1
- 2
- 3
- ("\n")
- 4

Comment: So "foo\n bar" should be two words, "foo\n" and "bar"?

Comment: So you want to print every newline that appears in the stream instead of ignoring it?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using so far?

Comment: And, ideally, what result you expect from some given input.

Comment: Thanks for the update but can you show the code where you're actually using the iterators to do the input please?

Comment: You want to open and read a file with an iterator, isn't it ?

Comment: @aloisdg Yes and sometimes it could be the std::cin

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `\\n`

Replace "\n" with "\\n" in your string. Dont forget `\r\n` too.

sample :

```
#include <iostream>

// searchAndReplace by Loki Astari http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452501/string-replace-in-c
// thanks to him

void searchAndReplace(std::string& value, std::string const& search,std::string const& replace)
{
  std::string::size_type  next;

  for(next = value.find(search);        // Try and find the first match
      next != std::string::npos;        // next is npos if nothing was found
      next = value.find(search,next)    // search for the next match starting after
    // the last match that was found.
      )
       {
          // Inside the loop. So we found a match.
          value.replace(next,search.length(),replace);   // Do the replacement.
          next += replace.length();                      // Move to just after the replace
              // This is the point were we start
          // the next search from.
        }
}

int main()
{
  std::string s = "123\n4\n5";
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  searchAndReplace(s, "\n", "\\n"); // just do this. you can check for /r/n too.
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Output :

```
123
4
5
123\n4\n5
```

Comment: What does filecontent while get in my 1 2 3\n4 exemple ?

Comment: You want to read `\n` as a return carriage or as a char `\` followed by the char `n` ?

Comment: I want my \n be a word :) like "\n" and not '\n' and not std::endl

Comment: OK ! Just replace `\n` by `\\n` in your string. The first `\` is going to stop the effect of the second.

Comment: You mean, "don't store newlines in the file you're reading". I'm sorry, but that is not a very good answer. Requiring changes in the file format is not the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, it helps! But if there is 1\\n2 It wont return
"1" "\n" "2" but "1\\n2". You get my point ?

Comment: @0x499602D2 nop I did not

Comment: I am not sure it is a good answer, but you can replace each '\' with '\\'. Another trick will be to replace each '\n' by 2 chars : '\' and 'n'. The problem is '\n' is one char. I guess a good way to do it is to split your string in lines and add `std::endl` when you print each.

Comment: @nsvir If you want some reading, check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx