# unexpected result removing a char from a string

Tags: c++, algorithm

For some reason the code below doesn't work. It looks to me like it has undefined behaviour but i can't figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void CIS_CIP_bdpm() {
    string str = "oui";
    string newStr;
    char ch = 'u';
    char ch2 = 'i';
    string boolStrOui = "oui";
    string boolStrNon = "non";
    auto it = std::search(str.begin(), str.end(), boolStrOui.begin(), boolStrOui.end());
    if (it != str.end()) { //replaces o from oui to 1, removes 'u' and 'i'
        *it = '1';
        it = std::remove(it, str.end(), ch);
        it = std::remove(it, str.end(), ch2);
    }
    newStr += str;
}
```

`str` has only the word "oui", i'd expect my program to replace o by 1, then remove u and then remove i. It simply does not work. I end up with `1ii`
Any idea ? Is the line of code `*it = '1';` okay?

Comment: If the issue is simply trying to do a search and replace, there is no need to post unnecessary things like reading from files.  Just a simple function that takes a source string, parameters denoting the search and replace string, and returns the changed string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you, edited the question removing the file parts.

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452501/string-replace-in-c)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This indeed solves what I was trying to do, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) for `std::remove` (emphasis mine):

> Removing is done by shifting the elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to be removed appear in the beginning of the range. Relative order of the elements that remain is preserved and the physical size of the container is unchanged.
>
> Iterators pointing to an element between the new logical end and the physical end of the range are still dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have unspecified values (as per MoveAssignable post-condition).
>
> **A call to remove is typically followed by a call to a container's erase method, which erases the unspecified values and reduces the physical size of the container to match its new logical size.**

So you want to do something like:

```
if (it != str.end()) { //replaces o from oui to 1, removes 'u' and 'i'
    *it = '1';
    auto it2 = std::remove(it, str.end(), ch);
    str.erase (it2, str.end ());
    it2 = std::remove(it, str.end(), ch2);
    str.erase (it2, str.end ());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand what went wrong now